# Given the following set, how do I determine the boundary, exterior and interior points?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

$$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: 2 \leq x <5, 1 < y \leq 4\}$$

1. Is $A$ open? Why or why not?
2. Is $A$ closed? Why or why not?
3. Determine the boundary points of $A$.
4. Determine the exterior points of $A$.
5. Determine the interior points of $A$.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I forgot to add this part - I can't find anywhere how to do this problem. More so than just getting the answer I'd like to understand how to do this problem.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of $A$?

Comment: Draw the region first.

Comment: No, I cannot. I don't particularly understand this topic, and even though this is an extra credit homework assignment I'd like to fully understand how to do this because eventually this sort of problem is going to be on a test/quiz.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $A\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is open if for every point $(x,y)\in A$ there is an *open disc* around $(x,y)$ that completely belongs to $A$, that is if there is some $r>0$ such that for all $(u,v)$ with $\sqrt{(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2}<r$ we have $(u,v)\in A$. 
Alternatively: $A$ is open if for every converging sequence of points *not* in $A$, their limit is also not in $A$.

A subset is closed if its complement is open.
Alternatively: $A$ is closed if for every converging sequence of points in $A$, their limit is aloso in $A$.

Here we have $(2,3)\in A$, but $(2+\frac1n,3)\notin A$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. So we have a sequence of points $\notin A$ that converges to a point $\in A$. Thus $A$ is not open.

Also, $(5-\frac1n,3)\in A$, but the limit $(5,3)\notin A$. Hence $A$ is not closed.

An interior point of $A$ is a point that does have an open disc belonging to $A$ around it. So in an open set all points would be interior. Likewise an exterior point is a point $\notin A$ having an open disc around it that is disjoint to $A$. So for a closed set, all points $\notin A$ would be exterior.
Boundary points are points (that are themselves either $\in A$ or $\notin A$) for which every open disc contains both points $\in A$ and points $\notin A$. Interior, exterior and boundary are thus a disjoint partition of $\mathbb R^2$.

The proof that $A$ is not open was done by exhibiting a point $(2,3)\in A$ that is a boundary point. The proof that $A$ is not closed worked by exhibiting a point $(5,3)\notin A$ that is a boundary point. You hsould notice that the same trick as abocve works with any of the points $(x,y)$ with $2\le x\le 5$ and $y=1$ or $=4$, and also with all points $(x,y)$ with $1\le y\le 4$ and $x=2$ or $=5$. Make a sketch of this! (That are four line segments that make up a rectangle). The set $A$ is the *interior* of this rectangle, plus the left edge, plus the top edge, but minus the lower left and the upper right vertex. (Check that!). From the *sketch* it should be cleear that the interior of the rectangle is precisely the set of interioir points of $A$: Each point there has a positive distance from the boundary, hence a sufficiently small disc stays inside. Similarly, all points outside the rectangle are exterioir points for similar reasons. After a look at the sketch you may want to give a mor formal description of the interior and exterior of $A$.

Comment: I still do not understand the question nor this reply at all. Are there any online resources where I can go to get myself educated on this topic?

Comment: I think I understand now. However, since set A was neither open nor closed, does that mean there are no interior/exterior points? What would be the boundary points for this set?